# How to get rid of the top header

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen, jdialog

How can I get rid of the top header of java containning the close button,minimize and maximize?

I want to make a plane Panel with no top header for loading of my program.

Like this
[Image here](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/3324/javagui.png)

I tried JDialog but it is not working for me

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class LoadingGui extends JDialog{
    JPanel jp;
    public LoadingGui()
    {
        setSize(400,400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void introGui()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: *"for loading of my program."*  Sound like a [`SplashScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
dialog.setUndecorated(true);
```

before the dialog is visible or packed.